# How to get color of Toolbar's/ActionBar's text color programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, textcolor

I'm trying to get toolbar's `textColor` using this method:

```
private int getToolbarTextColor() {

    int toolbarTextColor;
    TypedArray typedArray = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{R.attr.titleTextColor});

    try {
        toolbarTextColor = typedArray.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        toolbarTextColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    return toolbarTextColor;
}
```

but it returns `0`. What is the problem in my code? What attribute should I use? Is there another ***better*** way to get it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that uses reflection for obtaining a Toolbar title TextView's color:

```
@ColorInt public static int getToolbarTitleTextColor(Toolbar toolbar) {
try {
  Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) f.get(toolbar);
  if (mTitleTextView != null) {
    return mTitleTextView.getCurrentTextColor();
  }
} catch (Exception  e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

return 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think there should be an attribute which presents the color.

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, null, R.styleable.Toolbar, R.attr.toolbarStyle, 0);

title.setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.Toolbar_titleTextColor, -0x1))
subtitle.setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.Toolbar_titleTextColor, -0x1))
```

(Kotlin)

Comment: there is a warning that says the resource Toolbar_titleTextColor is marked as private using material library. Any idea?